# How to convert the contents of a variable to a string?

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I have 5 variables and I have 3 files.

```
$NumOne = Read-Host 'Enter four digit numone'
$NumTwo = Read-Host = 'Enter two digit numtwo'
$sdataJRN= $NumOne + $NumTwo + "00" + ".jrn"
$sdataJNM = $NumOne + $NumTwo + "00" + ".jnm"
$sdataTXN = $NumOne + $NumTwo + "00" + ".txn"
```

Right now the three files are 06540200.jnm and jrn and txn respectively.

I want to rename each of these files. Instead of being 00 at the end I want 99. 06540299 jrn jnm txn

I am doing this with the following lines:

```
Rename-Item $sdataJRN -NewName $NumOne,$NumTwo,"99",".jrn"

Rename-Item $sdataJNM -NewName $NumOne,$NumTwo,"99",".jnm"

Rename-Item $sdataTXN -NewName $NumOne,$NumTwo,"99",".txn"
```

This returns an error.

```
Rename-Item : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'NewName'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:34
+ Rename-Item $sdataJRN[0] -NewName <<<<  $storeNum,$regNum,"99",".jrn"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Comment: Try $($NumOne+$NumTwo+"99"+".jrn") just like your top code sample...

Comment: `"${NumOne}${NumTwo}99.jrn"`

Comment: The parameter `-NewName` expects a single string, not an array of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters), which allows you to derive a parameter value from each input object:

Note: As in your code, the assumption is that the input files are located in the current directory.

```
$sdataJRN, $sdataJNM, $sdataTXN |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_ -replace '00\.([^.]+)$', '99.$1' }
```

`{ ... }` is a delay-bind *script block* that is *evaluated for each input object*, and inside of it automatic variable `$_` refers to the input object at hand.

The `-replace` operator operates on regexes (regular expressions):

- `00\.([^.]+)$` matches `00` before a literal `.` (`\.`), followed by one ore more characters that aren't literal `.` (`[^.]`) at the end of the string (`$`).
- By enclosing `[^.]+` in `(...)`, the match - the filename extension, in this case - is captured so that it can be referenced in the replacement operand as `$1`, i.e., the *1st* (and in this case only) *capture group*.
- Replacement operand `99.$1` then replaces everything the regex matched with literal `99.`, followed by the value of `$1`, i.e., the value of the 1st capture group, i.e., the input filename extension.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `Rename-Item $sdataJRN -NewName $NumOne,$NumTwo,"99",".jrn"`

`$NumOne,$NumTwo,"99",".jrn"` is not a string-concatenation operation, it creates a *4-element array*, due to use of `,`, PowerShell's array-construction operator.

Since the `-NewName` operator is `[string]`-typed - i.e., a *single string*, trying to pass an *array* fails.

For a specific input name you could have used an *expandable string* to synthesize the `-NewName` argument:

```
Rename-Item $sdataJRN -NewName "${NumOne}${NumTwo}99.jrn"
```

That said, the delay-bind solution above offers more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to rename items:

```
Rename-Item $sdataJRN -NewName ($NumOne + $NumTwo + "99" + ".jrn")

Rename-Item $sdataJNM -NewName ($NumOne + $NumTwo + "99" + ".jnm")

Rename-Item $sdataTXN -NewName ($NumOne + $NumTwo + "99" + ".txn")
```